# Can't get id from another table in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Here's my code:

```
$user = new \App\User;
    $user -> role = 'anggota';
    $user -> name = $request -> nama;
    $user -> email = $request -> email;
    $user -> password = bcrypt('rahasia');
    $user -> remember_token = Str::random(60);
    $user -> save(); 


    //insert tabel anggota
    $request ->request->add(['user_id' => $user-> id]);
    $anggota = new angota([
        'nik' => $request -> input ('nik'),
        'nama' => $request -> input ('nama'),
        'tempat_lahir' => $request -> input ('tempat_lahir'),
        'tgl_lahir' => $request -> input ('tgl_lahir'),
        'jenis_kelamin' => $request -> input ('jenis_kelamin'),
        'pekerjaan' => $request -> input ('pekerjaan'),
        'agama' => $request -> input ('agama'),
        'gol_darah' => $request -> input ('gol_darah'),
        'alamat' => $request -> input ('alamat'),
        'email' => $request -> input ('email'),
        'no_hp' => $request -> input ('no_hp')

    ]);
```

I'm trying to get id from table user into table anggota but I get the following error:

```
"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $anggota = new angota([
      'user_id' => $user-> id,
      ... 
 ])
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing **user_id** to "**new angota ([**"